# A generic error occurred in GDI+. Image save

Tags: c#, asp.net, bitmap

Hi I have some problem about bitmap.save,In the first save it's not have problem,but on the second save i have some problem about this "A generic error occurred in GDI+" and this is my code

```
 System.Drawing.Bitmap img = coder.Encode(QR_Code);
 img.Save(string.Format("{0}\\{1}.jpg", pathServer, fileName), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

How to solve this problem .Thank you so much please help.

Comment: What value does `pathServer` have?

Comment: Filename or file path cannot contain these symbols =  / \ : ? * <> |  Check this rule.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to write over the same file and being precluded. It may be a permission issue. Try to save second one to another path.

Comment: Give permissions (Folder security -> Give full control to all users) to that folder in which your images are stored. If the problem still persists, then give permission to the entire application.